# CosmosDB SDK: System.IO.FileNotFoundException After Deploying to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have an Azure Function App written in C# to which I added a reference to the CosmosDB SDK version 3.31.  When I run the function app locally, it works fine, once I deploy it to Azure however I get a System.IO.FileNotFoundException indicating that Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client cannot be found.  I checked the dependencies set on the csproj file numerous times and everything seems to be correct.

I took a look at some Azure docs concerning troubleshooting which indicated that I should make sure that I'm using the most recent version of the SDK.  I had been using version 3.29, so I upgraded to 3.31 and I'm still seeing the error in the function app log in Azure.

I am a little at a loss so any help anyone could provide would be terrific.

Comment: And how exactly did you add the reference? And how do you deploy the application?

Comment: @PeterBons I added the reference using the nuget package manager in Visual Studio and deploy it using Build/Release pipelines in Azure DevOps.

Comment: The Cosmos DB package is Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos. Should not have "Client" included. The package reference should look like this, <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos" Version="3.31.0" />

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce the issue by creating a http triggered function (C#) in Visual Studio and added the CosmosDB SDK version `3.31`    through the nuget package manager as shown in below screenshot:

[image]

Agreed with @`Mark Brown` and added the same cosmos DB SDK version and after adding the SDK I have tested in my local environment successfully:

**Output screen in local environment:**
[image]
[image]

Then published to the Azure App Service from the VS  and tested the function in the Azure portal without any issues successfully as shown in the below output screen:

[image]
[image]

**Note**: Add the Cosmos DB SDK in the Nuget package manager and make sure to select (check box) your function app in VS as shown below:
[image]

Comment: OK, this is an oversight on my part.  The Cosmos SDK dependency is not being referenced in the function app directly, it's in a nuget package I created which is the actual dependency referenced by the function app.  I was able to try packing the nuget package locally and I could then reproduce the same error when running the function app referencing the locally created nuget package.  For the sake of  clarity the package reference to CosmosDB looks like this: <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos" Version="3.31.0" />